# How can I change the type of date dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, date, type-conversion

I have dates like **dd.mm.yyyy** format in SQLite DB. I want to convert them to **yyyy-mm-dd** format.

I tried different examples but they didn't work.

Comment: I don't know how you got there and all that, but let me suggest something anyway.  

You can split the string at the "." , save them as day, month and year individually and then write them back in with - as separator.

Comment: Thank u. I understand but how can i query like          x>dd.mm.yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [substr()](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-substr/) function to split into parts and the `||` operator to concatenate:

```
substr(datecolumn, 7) || '-' || substr(datecolumn, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(datecolumn, 1, 2)
```

The format `yyyy-mm-dd` is comparable, so you can compare dates like this:

```
date > substr(datecolumn, 7) || '-' || substr(datecolumn, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(datecolumn, 1, 2)
```

where `date` has the same format.